# Cleaning up a US county level choropleth

Tags: r, ggplot2, choropleth

I have gotten a choropleth scripted for US county level data, but upon plotting it am finding it hard to read. The counties can get very crowded and begin blending in to each other - it becomes difficult to tell where one state ends and another begins. Does anyone know a method of plotting a choropleth map by county data and creating border outlines by state? Here is the code I have so far for reproduction:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(fiftystater)
library(colorplaner)
library(USAboundaries)
library(sf)

usc <- us_counties(resolution = c("low", "high"), states = NULL)

st_list = c("Alabama", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", 
"Connecticut", "Delaware", "Florida", "Georgia", "Idaho", "Illinois", 
"Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", "Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", 
"Massachusetts", "Michigan", "Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", 
"Montana", "Nebraska", "Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New 
Mexico", "New York", "North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", 
"Oregon", "Pennsylvania", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", "South Dakota", 
"Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", "Washington", "West 
Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming")

plot_counties <- us_counties(states=st_list, resolution = 'high')


plot_counties$dumb <- runif(nrow(plot_counties), 1,100)

ggplot(plot_counties) + geom_sf(aes(fill=dumb)) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  scale_fill_gradientn("Title",
                       colours = c('darkred', 'tomato1', 'cyan2', 
                       'darkblue'), 
                       values = c(0,.5,.5000001, 1)) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.text = element_blank())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possibile solution:

```
plot_counties <- us_counties(states=st_list, resolution = 'high')
plot_counties$dumb <- runif(nrow(plot_counties), 1,100)
plot_states <- us_states(states=st_list, resolution = 'high')

ggplot(plot_counties) + 
  geom_sf(aes(fill=dumb), color=NA) + 
  geom_sf(data=plot_states, fill=NA, color="black", lwd=1) + 
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = NULL) + 
  scale_y_continuous(breaks = NULL) +
  scale_fill_gradientn("Title",
                       colours = c('darkred','tomato1','cyan2','darkblue'), 
                       values = c(0,.5,.5000001, 1)) + 
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), axis.ticks = element_blank(), 
        axis.text = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: That's a really clever solution. Thank you!